# r relative frequency polygon and histogram from binned data (or frequency table) using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, frequency

I'd like to start from some binned/aggregated data and draw the corresponding relative frequency polygon and a relative frequency histogram using `ggplot2`. Unfortunately, I can't use `geom_freqpoly` and `geom_histogram` directly as they require the raw data as input.

So how do I get the same nice ggplot2 freqpoly and histogram graphics, without the original raw data but provided only with the relative frequency/binned data?

Here is my binned data:

```
brks <- c(100, 130, 160, 200, 250, 300)
lows <- brks[1:length(brks)-1]
ups <- brks[2:length(brks)]
mids <- (lows + ups) / 2
bins <- paste("[", lows, " -- ", ups, "(", sep = "")
print(bins)

freq <- c(40, 50, 32, 7, 5)
rel_freq <- freq / sum(freq)
cum_rel_freq <- cumsum(rel_freq)

tbl <- data.frame(bins, freq, rel_freq, cum_rel_freq)
```

Tentative solution for "freqpoly" (I'd like to have `brks` on the x-axis):

```
ggplot(tbl, aes(x = brks, y = c(0, tbl$cum_rel_freq))) + geom_line() # This one results in an error
# plot(x = brks, y = c(0, cum_rel_freq)) # Close to what I'd like to get but in base graphics
```

Tentative solution for "histogram" (plus I'd like to have as class labels on the x-axis the `bins` at the `mids` as ticks) but I'm not quite there (I also played with `geom_area` and other geoms but to no avail):

```
ggplot(tbl, aes_(x = bins, y = rel_freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. For your first part you need to secify for the x values a name of a a column of `tbl`. You can try to `cbind` `brks` to `tbl`. For the second part, you can try this: `tbl <- data.frame(bins, freq, rel_freq, cum_rel_freq,mids);
ggplot(tbl, aes_(x = mids, y = rel_freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ 
   scale_x_continuous(labels = bins, breaks = mids)`

Comment: @Jimbou `scale_x_continuous(labels = bins, breaks = mids) ` failed with `"Error: Discrete value to continuous scale"`. What I want is to get the same nice ggplot2 freqpoly and histogram graphics, without the original raw data but only with relative frequency data.

Comment: @Jimbou I can't `cbind` `brks` to `tbl` in their current form as they've got different lengths.

Comment: So what is actually wrong with your plots? The look as your data is.

Comment: @Jimbou the histogram bars don't touch each other for example, because of the way it was built with a bar plot. Your suggestion to use `scale_x_continuous` results in an error. The freqpoly graph doesn't work at all as for now.